# iPhone Email Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an app which sends an email from the app.  Is there a way to automatically fill out the to section with the users default email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have access to this information for privacy reasons.

Your best bet is to prompt the user for their email sometime before starting the email composition.  Then remember it from then on and give a spot where they can change it.